# How to save audio file in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, audio, firebase-storage

I have successfully save an image,recorded the sound and save it in Firebase. But the audio file cannot save multiple file, when i try to save another recording, it will replace the old record and only have one file in Firebase. How can i save the new record without replacing the old one in Firebase?

```
Uri uriAudio = Uri.fromFile(new File(audioFilePath).getAbsoluteFile());
        final StorageReference filePath = ref.child("Education/image").child(uriImage.getLastPathSegment());
        final StorageReference audioRef = ref.child("Education/audio").child(uriAudio.getLastPathSegment());


                // on success upload audio
                audioRef.putFile(uriAudio).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot audioSnapshot) {

                        //upload image
                        filePath.putFile(uriImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot imageSnapshot) {

                                mProgress.dismiss();

                        @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri audioUrl= audioSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri imageUrl= imageSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
```

Here is the attachment for audio file in Firebase Storage
[image: Here is the attachment for audio file in Firebase Storage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. For this you need to specify each time you upload an audio file a different name for your audio file. If you keep uploading with the same name, your audio will be overridden each time. Unfortunately there is no built-in method to generate a unique audio filename for Firebase Storage (like the `push()` method in the Firebase database).

To have globally unique audio filenames, you'll have to generate those names yourself. One way would be to use the Firebase Database's **`push()`** method, but you can also use any other [GUID-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=generate+guid) you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use from the following two lines to generate *UniqueId*

- **Creating an Instance ID:**
  `String id = InstanceID.getInstance(context).getId()`
- **Creating a GUID:**
  `String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString`

Answer (score 0):

its work by using timestamp instead of file name, this is my old coding,

```
 audioFilePath =
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/myaudio.3gp";
```

Using timestamp is working to save multiple file,

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    audioFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + timeStamp;
```

Comment: And what will happen if two users will save an audio file in the same time? You'll end up having the same problem. Your data will be overridden. Using `push()` method, there is no way to have this problem. Furthermore, `push()` method is based on time...